# Theme JQuery inlcusion on Wordpress 6.0 always fails

Tags: jquery

I am writing here because i have Wordpress 6.0, i am trying to include JQuery in my theme beacuse i have to start working on a functionality i need. The problem is that JQuery is not loading correctly i guess because in my chrome developer console i got this error:

[image]

[image]

Jquery is not recognized but i don't undersand why, because i have always followed Wordpress practices and as you can see below in the code apparently there is nothing wrong. Wordpress has already its own Jquery, i don't want an external Jquery library even in CDN, i don't think is needed another JQuery.

Here is the code for enqueuing additional js scripts in functions.php:

```
function load_custom_jquery_edit(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_enqueue_script('customize-jq', 
                    get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/customize-jq.js',
                    array('jquery'),
                    "1.1.0",
                    true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_jquery_edit');
```

This is my JQuery additional file:

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    //testing example
    $('test-my-new-submit-btn')
    .attr('id','testBtn');

    $('#testBtn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    
        let success_msg = "success!!!";
        
        alert(success_msg);
                    
        //Other things to do next
    });
});
})(JQuery);
```

Comment: It’s referencing “JQuery” which I think should be lowercase “jQuery” instead.

Comment: Yeah that was that mistake, thank you so much i didn't realize the mispelled jQuery reference, unfortunatelt i am new to Wordpress development. Now i have another problem that is quite strange and unique about the ajax call to a custom php script and it gives me back the http 403 forbidden error i suppose. I used the nonce wordpress security as suggested but still 403.